# Exporting Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

One of the stack overflow buddies was kind enough to give me a below code for creating a dictionary. This works well. But now I want to export the data frames in the dictionary into a single CSV file. Can someone please help me with this?

```
import pandas as pd
DF1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [3], "B": [2], "C": [100]})
DF_list = {}
 for i in ["A", "B"]:
 DF = pd.DataFrame({})
 DF[i] = DF1[[i]]
 DF["C"] = DF1[["C"]]
 DF["value"] = DF[i] * DF["C"]
 DF_list["DF_" + i] = DF

print(DF_list)
{'DF_A':    A    C  value
 0  3  100    300, 'DF_B':    B    C  value
 0  2  100    200}
```

Comment: what have you tried? you need to show some initiative in solving the problem...

Comment: just to close a loop on this ....i ended up concatenating all the dataframes in the list into a single dataframe and then exporting out as a CSV